# Conditional state in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

Let's say i have these initial states

```
this.state = {schedules: [], status: 'morning'}
```

and object of dynamic schedules JSON fetched from an API that could change over certain day.. e.g.

```
schedules = {"morning": "6:30", "midday": "13:00", "afternoon":"17:30", "night":"21:00"}
```

now how can i change `this.state.status` respectively on currently time difference? e.g. `curTime = '14:30'`, so `this.state.status = 'midday'`

The purpose of this is to style each schedules component differently (based on `this.state.status`) e.g.  `style={{color: this.state.status == 'morning' ? 'red' : 'black'}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function similar to this should work

```
updateStatus(){
   const keys = Object.keys(this.state.schedules).reverse();
   for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       if(curTime > this.state.schedules[keys[i]]) {
           this.setState({status:keys[i]});
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Only thing you will have to think about is how to compare times.

Comment: `curTime = moment(new Date()).format('H')` and `parseInt(this.state.schedules[keys[i]].substring(0, this.state.schedules[keys[i]].indexOf(':')))` maybe it's not as accurate as by getting minutes, but it's fine to me. thanks!